# Upgrading from 4.0.4 to 4.0.10 - TypeError: Can't use implementer with classes. Use one of the class-declaration functions instead

Tags: plone, dexterity

I have a (working) Plone 4.0.4 site that uses Dexterity.  I am trying to upgrade it to 4.0.10.  When I start an instance on the new (4.0.10) site, I get the error:

```
    TypeError: Can't use implementer with classes.  Use one of the class-declaration functions instead.
```

(Full backtrace below)
This error seems to come from `zope.interface`, and obviously it must be caused by some problem with the new site's version set, because everything else is the same.  The versions of `plone.app.dexterity` and `zope.interface` are the same on both sites.

I don't know where to look for a solution, any suggestion welcome!

traceback:  http://pastie.org/8506203

bin/instance:  http://pastie.org/8506250

Thanks!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/Zope2-2.12.20-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/OFS/Application.py", line 671, in install_product
    initmethod(context)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/Zope2-2.12.20-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/Products/Five/__init__.py", line 31, in initialize
    zcml.load_site()
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/Zope2-2.12.20-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/Products/Five/zcml.py", line 51, in load_site
    _context = xmlconfig.file(file)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 647, in file
    include(context, name, package)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 546, in include
    processxmlfile(f, context)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 378, in processxmlfile
    parser.parse(src)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 107, in parse
    xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
    self.feed(buffer)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 207, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 349, in end_element_ns
    self._cont_handler.endElementNS(pair, None)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 357, in endElementNS
    self.context.end()
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 537, in end
    self.stack.pop().finish()
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 685, in finish
    actions = self.handler(context, **args)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/Zope2-2.12.20-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/Products/Five/fiveconfigure.py", line 74, in loadProducts
    handleBrokenProduct(product)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/Zope2-2.12.20-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/Products/Five/fiveconfigure.py", line 72, in loadProducts
    xmlconfig.include(_context, zcml, package=product)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 546, in include
    processxmlfile(f, context)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 378, in processxmlfile
    parser.parse(src)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 107, in parse
    xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
    self.feed(buffer)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 207, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 349, in end_element_ns
    self._cont_handler.endElementNS(pair, None)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 357, in endElementNS
    self.context.end()
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 537, in end
    self.stack.pop().finish()
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 685, in finish
    actions = self.handler(context, **args)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/z3c.autoinclude-0.3.5-py2.6.egg/z3c/autoinclude/zcml.py", line 104, in includePluginsDirective
    includeZCMLGroup(_context, info, filename)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/z3c.autoinclude-0.3.5-py2.6.egg/z3c/autoinclude/zcml.py", line 30, in includeZCMLGroup
    include(_context, filename, includable_package)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 546, in include
    processxmlfile(f, context)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 378, in processxmlfile
    parser.parse(src)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 107, in parse
    xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
    self.feed(buffer)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 207, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 349, in end_element_ns
    self._cont_handler.endElementNS(pair, None)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 357, in endElementNS
    self.context.end()
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 537, in end
    self.stack.pop().finish()
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 685, in finish
    actions = self.handler(context, **args)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/z3c.autoinclude-0.3.5-py2.6.egg/z3c/autoinclude/zcml.py", line 54, in includeDependenciesDirective
    includeZCMLGroup(_context, info, 'configure.zcml')
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/z3c.autoinclude-0.3.5-py2.6.egg/z3c/autoinclude/zcml.py", line 30, in includeZCMLGroup
    include(_context, filename, includable_package)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 546, in include
    processxmlfile(f, context)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 378, in processxmlfile
    parser.parse(src)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 107, in parse
    xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
    self.feed(buffer)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 207, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 349, in end_element_ns
    self._cont_handler.endElementNS(pair, None)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 357, in endElementNS
    self.context.end()
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 537, in end
    self.stack.pop().finish()
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 685, in finish
    actions = self.handler(context, **args)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 546, in include
    processxmlfile(f, context)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 378, in processxmlfile
    parser.parse(src)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 107, in parse
    xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
    self.feed(buffer)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 207, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 349, in end_element_ns
    self._cont_handler.endElementNS(pair, None)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 357, in endElementNS
    self.context.end()
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 537, in end
    self.stack.pop().finish()
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 684, in finish
    args = toargs(context, *self.argdata)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 1376, in toargs
    args[str(name)] = field.fromUnicode(s)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/fields.py", line 139, in fromUnicode
    value = self.context.resolve(name)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 180, in resolve
    mod = __import__(mname, *_import_chickens)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/plone.app.dexterity-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/plone/app/dexterity/browser/types.py", line 14, in <module>
    from plone.z3cform.crud import crud
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/plone.z3cform-0.7.8-py2.6.egg/plone/z3cform/crud/crud.py", line 14, in <module>
    import z3c.batching.batch
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/z3c.batching-2.0.0-py2.6.egg/z3c/batching/batch.py", line 27, in <module>
    class Batch(object):
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.interface-3.5.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/zope/interface/declarations.py", line 496, in __call__
    raise TypeError("Can't use implementer with classes.  Use one of "
ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/parts/instance1/etc/site.zcml", line 16.2-16.23
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/Plone-4.0.10-py2.6.egg/Products/CMFPlone/configure.zcml", line 94.4-98.10
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/src/ecobuilding.content/ecobuilding/content/configure.zcml", line 10.4-10.39
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/plone.app.dexterity-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/plone/app/dexterity/configure.zcml", line 33.4-33.34
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/plone.app.dexterity-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/plone/app/dexterity/browser/configure.zcml", line 47.4-52.51
    TypeError: Can't use implementer with classes.  Use one of the class-declaration functions instead.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/Zope2-2.12.20-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/Zope2/Startup/run.py", line 56, in <module>
    run()
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/Zope2-2.12.20-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/Zope2/Startup/run.py", line 21, in run
    starter.prepare()
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/Zope2-2.12.20-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/Zope2/Startup/__init__.py", line 87, in prepare
    self.startZope()
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/Zope2-2.12.20-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/Zope2/Startup/__init__.py", line 264, in startZope
    Zope2.startup()
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/Zope2-2.12.20-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/Zope2/__init__.py", line 47, in startup
    _startup()
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/Zope2-2.12.20-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/Zope2/App/startup.py", line 116, in startup
    OFS.Application.initialize(application)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/Zope2-2.12.20-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/OFS/Application.py", line 251, in initialize
    initializer.initialize()
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/Zope2-2.12.20-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/OFS/Application.py", line 279, in initialize
    self.install_products()
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/Zope2-2.12.20-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/OFS/Application.py", line 492, in install_products
    return install_products(app)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/Zope2-2.12.20-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/OFS/Application.py", line 523, in install_products
    folder_permissions, raise_exc=debug_mode)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/Zope2-2.12.20-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/OFS/Application.py", line 671, in install_product
    initmethod(context)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/Zope2-2.12.20-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/Products/Five/__init__.py", line 31, in initialize
    zcml.load_site()
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/Zope2-2.12.20-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/Products/Five/zcml.py", line 51, in load_site
    _context = xmlconfig.file(file)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 647, in file
    include(context, name, package)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 546, in include
    processxmlfile(f, context)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 378, in processxmlfile
    parser.parse(src)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 107, in parse
    xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
    self.feed(buffer)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 207, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 349, in end_element_ns
    self._cont_handler.endElementNS(pair, None)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 357, in endElementNS
    self.context.end()
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 537, in end
    self.stack.pop().finish()
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 685, in finish
    actions = self.handler(context, **args)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/Zope2-2.12.20-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/Products/Five/fiveconfigure.py", line 74, in loadProducts
    handleBrokenProduct(product)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/Zope2-2.12.20-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/Products/Five/fiveconfigure.py", line 72, in loadProducts
    xmlconfig.include(_context, zcml, package=product)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 546, in include
    processxmlfile(f, context)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 378, in processxmlfile
    parser.parse(src)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 107, in parse
    xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
    self.feed(buffer)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 207, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 349, in end_element_ns
    self._cont_handler.endElementNS(pair, None)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 357, in endElementNS
    self.context.end()
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 537, in end
    self.stack.pop().finish()
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 685, in finish
    actions = self.handler(context, **args)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/z3c.autoinclude-0.3.5-py2.6.egg/z3c/autoinclude/zcml.py", line 104, in includePluginsDirective
    includeZCMLGroup(_context, info, filename)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/z3c.autoinclude-0.3.5-py2.6.egg/z3c/autoinclude/zcml.py", line 30, in includeZCMLGroup
    include(_context, filename, includable_package)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 546, in include
    processxmlfile(f, context)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 378, in processxmlfile
    parser.parse(src)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 107, in parse
    xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
    self.feed(buffer)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 207, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 349, in end_element_ns
    self._cont_handler.endElementNS(pair, None)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 357, in endElementNS
    self.context.end()
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 537, in end
    self.stack.pop().finish()
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 685, in finish
    actions = self.handler(context, **args)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/z3c.autoinclude-0.3.5-py2.6.egg/z3c/autoinclude/zcml.py", line 54, in includeDependenciesDirective
    includeZCMLGroup(_context, info, 'configure.zcml')
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/z3c.autoinclude-0.3.5-py2.6.egg/z3c/autoinclude/zcml.py", line 30, in includeZCMLGroup
    include(_context, filename, includable_package)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 546, in include
    processxmlfile(f, context)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 378, in processxmlfile
    parser.parse(src)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 107, in parse
    xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
    self.feed(buffer)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 207, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 349, in end_element_ns
    self._cont_handler.endElementNS(pair, None)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 357, in endElementNS
    self.context.end()
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 537, in end
    self.stack.pop().finish()
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 685, in finish
    actions = self.handler(context, **args)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 546, in include
    processxmlfile(f, context)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 378, in processxmlfile
    parser.parse(src)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 107, in parse
    xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
    self.feed(buffer)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 207, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
  File "/usr/local/python_git/parts/opt/lib/python2.6/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 349, in end_element_ns
    self._cont_handler.endElementNS(pair, None)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py", line 357, in endElementNS
    self.context.end()
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 537, in end
    self.stack.pop().finish()
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 684, in finish
    args = toargs(context, *self.argdata)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 1376, in toargs
    args[str(name)] = field.fromUnicode(s)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/fields.py", line 139, in fromUnicode
    value = self.context.resolve(name)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.configuration-3.6.0-py2.6.egg/zope/configuration/config.py", line 180, in resolve
    mod = __import__(mname, *_import_chickens)
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/plone.app.dexterity-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/plone/app/dexterity/browser/types.py", line 14, in <module>
    from plone.z3cform.crud import crud
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/plone.z3cform-0.7.8-py2.6.egg/plone/z3cform/crud/crud.py", line 14, in <module>
    import z3c.batching.batch
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/z3c.batching-2.0.0-py2.6.egg/z3c/batching/batch.py", line 27, in <module>
    class Batch(object):
  File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/zope.interface-3.5.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/zope/interface/declarations.py", line 496, in __call__
    raise TypeError("Can't use implementer with classes.  Use one of "
zope.configuration.xmlconfig.ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/parts/instance1/etc/site.zcml", line 16.2-16.23
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/Plone-4.0.10-py2.6.egg/Products/CMFPlone/configure.zcml", line 94.4-98.10
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/src/ecobuilding.content/ecobuilding/content/configure.zcml", line 10.4-10.39
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/plone.app.dexterity-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/plone/app/dexterity/configure.zcml", line 33.4-33.34
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/usr/local/zope/prod/Zope-2.12.20/plone4.0.10/eggs/plone.app.dexterity-1.2.1-py2.6.egg/plone/app/dexterity/browser/configure.zcml", line 47.4-52.51
    TypeError: Can't use implementer with classes.  Use one of the class-declaration functions instead.
```

Answer (score 3):

This error refers to the use of 'implementer' as a class decorator, e.g.:

```
@implementer(IBatch)
class Batch(object):
    ...
```

'implementer' as a class decorator was introduced in zope.interface 4.0.0 in order to support Python 3, where the classic "class advice" mechanism used by 'implements' no longer works.

Plone 4.0 does not use such a new version of zope.interface. Your problem is happening because you're ending up with too new a version of z3c.batching, which tries to use 'implementer.' This suggests that you haven't correctly pinned the set of versions for Dexterity with Plone 4.0.10.

You can find the correct set of pins here: http://good-py.appspot.com/release/dexterity/1.2.1?plone=4.0.10

Answer (score 1):

As luck would have it, I do have the tarball of a working copy of the site, so after painstakingly pinning down all versions, I was able to get to a starting Zope.
No guarantees, but these are the version pins I have so far:

```
http://dist.plone.org/release/4.0.10/versions.cfg

Products.PloneHotfix20110720 = 1.1
Products.PloneHotfix20110531 = 2.0
Products.PloneHotfix20110928 = 1.1
Products.PloneHotfix20130618 = 1.3
Products.PloneHotfix20121106 = 1.2
Products.Zope-Hotfix-20110622 = 1.0

Products.TinyMCE = 1.2.12
plone.autoform = 1.1

Products.Maps = 3.3
fourdigits.portlet.twitter = 1.0a14
collective.js.moment = 1.0.1
buildout.sanitycheck = 1.0b1

Products.TinyMCE = 1.2.12
z3c.form = 2.4.4
zope.schema = 3.7.1
zope.browserresource = 3.9.0
z3c.baseregistry = 1.2.0
Products.PloneFormGen = 1.6.7
zc.table = 0.8.0
five.intid = 0.5.0
collective.pfg.creditcardfields = 1.2
plone.dexterity = 1.1.2
zope.filerepresentation = 3.6.0
five.grok = 1.1.1
plone.app.intid = 1.0b3
Products.DataGridField = 1.8a1
Products.PloneKeywordManager = 1.8
ZODB3 = 3.9.7
Zope2 = 2.12.22
beatbox = 19.0
collective.autopermission = 1.0b1
collective.googleanalytics = 1.4
collective.monkeypatcher = 1.0.1
collective.recaptcha = 1.1.1
collective.salesforce.authplugin = 1.5
collective.z3cform.datetimewidget = 1.1.1
collective.z3cform.wizard = 1.3.3
dateable.kalends = 0.5
grokcore.annotation = 1.1
grokcore.component = 1.7
grokcore.formlib = 1.4
grokcore.security = 1.2
grokcore.site = 1.1
grokcore.view = 1.12.2
grokcore.viewlet = 1.3
hexagonit.swfheader = 1.0.1
martian = 0.11.2
p4a.common = 1.0.6
pfg.donationform = 1.1
plone.app.caching = 1.0b1
plone.app.discussion = 1.1
plone.app.registry = 1.0b2
plone.app.relationfield = 1.1
plone.app.uuid = 1.0b2
plone.app.z3cform = 0.5.7
plone.autoform = 1.1
plone.cachepurging = 1.0b1
plone.caching = 1.0b1
plone.formwidget.contenttree = 1.0.5
plone.outputfilters = 1.6
plone.registry = 1.0b2
plone.supermodel = 1.0.3
plone.transformchain = 1.0b1
plone.uuid = 1.0b2
python_dateutil = 1.5
qi.portlet.TagClouds = 1.32
z3c.batching = 1.1.0
zc.resourcelibrary = 1.3.1

z3c.autoinclude = 0.3.5

Pillow = 2.2.1
Products.Carousel = 2.2
Products.Clouseau = 1.0
Products.DocFinderTab = 1.0.5
Products.EasyAsPiIE = 0.92
Products.Gloworm = 1.0
Products.MasterSelectWidget = 0.4.4
Products.PDBDebugMode = 1.3.1
Products.PloneGetPaid = 0.10.4
Products.PressRoom = 3.13
Products.PythonField = 1.1.3
Products.RedirectionTool = 1.3
Products.Scrawl = 2.0b1
Products.TemplateFields = 1.2.5
Products.cron4plone = 1.1.5rc1
Products.salesforcebaseconnector = 1.4
Products.salesforcepfgadapter = 1.9.1
buildout.sanitycheck = 1.0b1
collective.plonetruegallery = 1.0
collective.recipe.bootstrap = 1.0
collective.recipe.filestorage = 0.6
collective.recipe.plonesite = 1.8.2
collective.salesforce.rsvp = 1.3
collective.sharerizer = 1.0
collective.uploadify = 1.0rc3
collective.weightedportlets = 1.1
ftw.calendar = 1.12
gdata = 2.0.17
getpaid.authorizedotnet = 0.6.5
getpaid.core = 0.9.2
getpaid.formgen = 0.4
p4a.calendar = 2.0a3
p4a.subtyper = 1.1.3
plone.behavior = 1.0.1
plone.directives.form = 1.0
plone.formwidget.autocomplete = 1.2.3
plone.formwidget.recaptcha = 1.0b3
plone.namedfile = 1.0.6
plone.rfc822 = 1.0
plone.schemaeditor = 1.2.0
recaptcha-client = 1.0.6
z3c.blobfile = 0.1.5
z3c.caching = 2.0a1
z3c.relationfield = 0.6.1
zc.authorizedotnet = 1.3.1
zc.relation = 1.0

# Required by:
# getpaid.authorizedotnet==0.6.5
M2Crypto = 0.21.1

# Required by:
# Products.salesforcepfgadapter==1.9.1
Products.TALESField = 1.1.3

collective.z3cform.datagridfield = 0.10

# Required by:
# plone.cachepurging==1.0b1
# plone.caching==1.0b1
five.globalrequest = 1.0

getpaid.nullpayment = 0.5.0

# Required by:
# Products.PloneGetPaid==0.10.4
getpaid.wizard = 0.4

# Required by:
# getpaid.core==0.9.2
hurry.workflow = 0.9.2-getpaid

# Required by:
# Products.PloneGetPaid==0.10.4
ore.viewlet = 0.2.2-getpaid

# Required by:
# p4a.subtyper==1.1.3
p4a.z2utils = 1.0.2

# Required by:
# plone.dexterity==1.1.2
plone.alterego = 1.0

plone.app.dexterity = 1.2.1

# Required by:
# plone.app.dexterity==1.2.1
plone.app.textfield = 1.2.1

# Required by:
# plone.app.dexterity==1.2.1
plone.directives.dexterity = 1.0.2

# Required by:
# plone.app.dexterity==1.2.1
plone.formwidget.namedfile = 1.0.2

# Required by:
# plone.dexterity==1.1.2
plone.synchronize = 1.0.1

# Required by:
# collective.z3cform.wizard==1.3.3
# plone.app.discussion==1.1
# plone.formwidget.recaptcha==1.0b3
plone.z3cform = 0.7.8

# Required by:
# plone.app.caching==1.0b1
python-dateutil = 2.2

# Required by:
# plone.dexterity==1.1.2
rwproperty = 1.0

# Required by:
# python-dateutil==2.2
six = 1.4.1

# Required by:
# Products.PloneGetPaid==0.10.4
yoma.batching = 0.2.2-getpaid

# Required by:
# plone.app.z3cform==0.5.7
z3c.formwidget.query = 0.9

# Required by:
# z3c.relationfield==0.6.1
z3c.objpath = 1.0

# Required by:
# plone.app.caching==1.0b1
z3c.zcmlhook = 1.0b1

# Required by:
# zc.authorizedotnet==1.3.1
zc.creditcard = 1.0

# Required by:
# zc.authorizedotnet==1.3.1
zc.ssl = 1.2

# Required by:
# five.globalrequest==1.0
zope.globalrequest = 1.0


Genshi = 0.7
Products.BeakerSessionDataManager = 1.1
collective.logbook = 0.6
collective.recipe.template = 1.10
z3c.offlinepack = 0.2
z3c.recipe.usercrontab = 1.1

# Required by:
# collective.beaker==1.0b3
Beaker = 1.6.4

# Required by:
# Products.BeakerSessionDataManager==1.1
collective.beaker = 1.0b3
```